# BeautifulSoup - str object has no attribute findAll

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm using BeautifulSoup to crawl stock ticker data, but I'm running into an issue using `findAll()`

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import collections

def findCSV(soupPage):
    CSV_URL_PREFIX = 'http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s='
    links = soupPage.findAll('a')
    for link in links:
        href = link.get('href', '')
        if href.startswith(CSV_URL_PREFIX):
            return href
```

I get the error:

> str object has no attribute findAll

I'm not sure what's causing this problem, because I have used `findAll()` successfully in the past in a very similar implementation.

Comment: What are you passing in to the function? It's a string, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is not in the code sample that you have provided: as the error message indicates, you have called the `findCSV` function passing it a string.

```
 # you did this:
 my_string = "hello"
 findCSV(my_string)

 # instead of
 soup = BeautifulSoup('<html..></html>')
 findCSV(soup)
```